# Why sed giving me new file as a backup file instead of original file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, backup, pipeline

In folder TM_only, I put the command to execute,

```
awk '{print $1}' ~/desktop/file/N-glyco-TM-common/baker.txt \
| xargs -n1 -I name sed -i.txt '/name/d' ~/desktop/file/TM_only/baker.txt
```

What it does is to remove the contents in the TM-common baker.txt file from TM_only baker.txt. The code is of no problem, but when it creates a BACKUP file baker.txt.txt(or bak) then it actually contains the new file(after removing lines) instead of original file.

Original file has 1668 lines, whereas new baker.txt has 407. However baker.txt.txt(BACKUP) too gives 407 instead of 1668.

Comment: your problem sounds like the result of a mistake in testing, where your `baker.txt` file got trimmed and  you didn't notice it, thus messing up any following tests. Did you try just the `sed` part on a new/clean file? (It should work as you expect). Good luck.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure about  your use of `-I name .. '/name/d`. The customary use is for `-I {} sed '/deleteTarget/d' {}` (so that `{}` holds the current filename being processed by `xargs`). Good luck.

Comment: Instead of using a pipeline with `awk` and `sed`, you could handle the whole problem with `awk`.